Цикл for выполняется не разом, а раз в секунду проходит по следующему элементу массива python
пытаюсь получить данные по нескольким монетам биржи разом, но почему-то при выполнении скрипта данные по каждой следующей монете приходят раз в секунду. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать, работаю с питоном в 1 день
tickers = ['DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 'BTCUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']

num = len(tickers)
cur_num = 1

oi_data_full = {}

for index, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    oi_data_full[cur_num] = um_futures_client.open_interest(ticker)
    print(oi_data_full[cur_num])

Если же прописывать каждую монету в отдельную переменную, то вся информация приходит разом
oi_data_full1 = um_futures_client.open_interest("BTCISDT")
oi_data_full2 = um_futures_client.open_interest("DOGEUSDT")
oi_data_full3 = um_futures_client.open_interest("ETHUSDT")
oi_data_full4 = um_futures_client.open_interest("1000PEPEUSDT")

Такая комбинация так же не срабатывает
tickers = ['DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 'BTCUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']

num = len(tickers)

i = 1

while i < num:
    for index, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
        globals()['oi_data_full' + str(index)] = um_futures_client.open_interest(ticker)
        print(oi_data_full[i])
        i += 1


Ну у вас cur_num не меняется. Тогда уж в цикле index надо использовать при присваивании.
Помимо прочего, здесь достаточно использовать список, словарь - излишество.

Спасибо за ответ, но не понял.
Мне выдаются эти результаты один за другим каждую секунду, а мне нужно получать их (которые есть в массиве) за 1 секунду:
{'symbol': 'DOGEUSDT', 'openInterest': '2209602670', 'time': 1712420131288}
Далее в качестве массива собирать ключ openInterest (для каждой монеты) и уже потом производить с ним вычисления (опять же для каждой монеты

Для уточнения: сейчас в tickers 6 монет, при выполнении скрипта раз в секунду приходят данные со следующей монетой массива в таком формате {'symbol': 'МОНЕТА', 'openInterest': '2209602670', 'time': 1712420131288} . А мне нужно чтобы приходило сразу 6 результатов

Как мне кажется - нужно создать "пакет" из запросов типа oi_data_full_1 = um_futures_client.open_interest("BTCUSDT") --- oi_data_full_2 = um_futures_client.open_interest("ETHUSDT") и т.д. чтобы получать все данные разом, чтобы далее можно было с oi_data_full_1 и oi_data_full_2 при каждом получении данных сразу производить вычисление

from time import sleep
tickers = ['DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 'BTCUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT', 'ORDIUSDT', 
'BTCUSDT']
while True:
    oi_data_full = {}

    for ticker in tickers:
        oi_data_full[ticker] = um_futures_client.open_interest(ticker)
    print(oi_data_full)
    sleep(1)

вывод 
'DOGEUSDT': данные - 'DOGEUSDT'
'ORDIUSDT': данные - 'ORDIUSDT'
и т.д.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
